# Discord.py get users status

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have seen that this was posted previously two years ago but that does not work. The bot should use info in that server. All the info is correct other than status. with the status it detects everyone as offline when they are online.

```
#gets user info of user on the discord
@client.command(aliases=["userinfo"] ,help = "Finds info about users on the discord.")
async def info(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"{user}'s info", description=f"Here's {user}'s info", color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name="Username:", value=user.name, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="ID:", value=user.id, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Status:", value=user.status, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Highest Role:", value=user.top_role, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Joined:", value=user.joined_at, inline=True)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

sorry if I have missed something obvious but I thought that this should work. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: I would recommend switching from discord.py as it no longer maintained, you could use a fork like Pycord, which uses the same discord namespace, so you probably won't need to change code,

Comment: Discord added presence intent settings a year ago, you'll need to enable the settings in the dev portal and in your code. This is needed to view user status/activity.

Comment: @Taku That did not work it is still giving the same outcome. I left it a bit to see if the changes needed time to applied but no luck

Comment: Remember to enable presence intent in the discord.py `Bot()` constructor, only enabling in the portal wouldn't change anything.

Comment: @Taku I believe I have done that and it is still not working I have added this to the start of my code 
https://pastebin.com/rtzMfq8K

Comment: The intent is called "presences", you'll need set that to True. I don't see it in your constructor.